# pm2 cpu-usage over 100%

Tags: node.js, cpu-usage, pm2

I run my webapps by `pm2` with `cluster` mode in Windows. Everything runs well.
However, when I run `pm2 list`,sometimes I may see that the cpu-usage of some work process is over 100%.
According to my understanding, one work process can only use one cpu which means the max cpu-usage must be not higher than 100%.
Why does `pm2` show the cpu-usage over 100%?

Comment: I too recently have faced this same exact issue. Without without cluster mode, cpu will plateau at 100%